# How to use Face to direct turtle movement toward a cone

Tags: netlogo

How do you direct turtle movement into a cone? I want turtles to move into a cone of highest chemical. I tried face cone, but it triggered the error that

```
nothing named cone has been defined.
```

I am aware that uphill-chemical is an existing way to direct turtle movement, but it is not working in my model, since the turtles wander in and out of the trail, instead of clearly following it towards one direction.

My proposed code is:

```
to uphill-total-chemical-scent-in-cone
  let gradient-color red  ;; gradients are a temporary debugging feature
  let scent-ahead total-chemical-scent-in-cone 20 0 10
  let scent-ahead-2 total-chemical-scent-in-cone 20 -45 10
  let scent-ahead-3 total-chemical-scent-in-cone 20 45 10
  ifelse (scent-ahead-2 > scent-ahead) or (scent-ahead-3 > scent-ahead)
  [ ifelse scent-ahead-3 > scent-ahead-2
    [ face cone 20 45 10 hatch-gradients 1 [set color gradient-color ]]        ;;
```

not sure how to direct movement into the cone, but could try face or some variation/ask for help

```
    [ face cone 21 -45 10 hatch-gradients 1 [set color gradient-color ]]]
  [face cone 20 0 10 hatch-gradients 1 [ set color gradient-color fd 1]] 
end
```

Comment: You're asking several questions here. Are you trying to make `uphill` work? Or define a patch-set called cone? I think the basic problem is that `face` requires a specific point to face - like a turtle or (the centre of) a patch. You can't say 'face a group of stuff' because that doesn't say what to face.

Comment: I think this was answered in the netllogo-users google group.